# Excel: Sumproduct - Import date from CSV file

Tags: excel

I am importing a lot of data from a csv file to my xml file. But i have a problem importing a date fra the csv file. I use sumproduct to retrieve the date since i need 3 things to be true before returning a date.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
     (maler.csv!$B$4:$B$500=Data!$B$3)*
     (maler.csv!$F$4:$F$500=Data!$A$4)*
     (maler.csv!$H$4:$H$500=1);
      maler.csv!$I$4:$I$500)
```

But instead of returning 03-02-2011 (danish date format) it returns 00-01-00.

I have tried formating cells to date, but it doenst help me.

Does anyone have a good idear ???

btw - i am using excel 2003 US

Regards - Kim

Comment: From your description it sounds as if you should change the title to "Excel: SUMPRODUCT usage".

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that your "maler.csv" worksheet matches the selection on your "Data" sheet, then you can verify if the computation is as you expect by simply formatting is as a number. The date 2011-02-03 should be seen as 40577. If not, then you should either look at the formula or at your data.

Comment: i can see that every cell in maler.csv is standard an not date format - this is done automatic from the export. Ive tried to format the entire column as date - but it didnt help.

Comment: You need to have excel to apply the new format. See for example http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Excel/microsoft.public.excel.misc/2008-11/msg06901.html

Comment: That didnt work - i have to manually enter the date for it to work.

Comment: I would expect the Data --> Text To Columns trick to work, but you can also do it via the VALUE() function. See for example http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/value-function-HP010062583.aspx